# Unable to import native nodejs module in electron project

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, nodegit, native-module

I'm working on an open source electron project which I am building using webpack.  One requirement for my project is to use the [nodegit](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit) library which has to be built as a native module.

I've followed what appears to be conventional advice when working with native modules and electron.  That is, I [run electron-rebuild](https://github.com/atrauzzi/gerty/blob/262351f756f2394968ee0857c5e3793e89413c86/package.json#L10), have [configured the source package to use](https://github.com/atrauzzi/gerty/blob/262351f756f2394968ee0857c5e3793e89413c86/.npmrc) and finally [have configured node-loader](https://github.com/atrauzzi/gerty/blob/262351f756f2394968ee0857c5e3793e89413c86/webpack.config.renderers.ts#L33-L36) to catch the import of any `.node` files.

Unfortunately, when I go to include the module, I end up with this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/nodegit/dist/nodegit.js
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../build/Debug/nodegit.node' in 
 'C:\Users\atrauzzi\Development\atrauzzi\gerty\node_modules\nodegit\dist'
  @ ./node_modules/nodegit/dist/nodegit.js 18:11-49
  @ ./src/Layer/Domain/Thunktor/Git/CloneGitRepository.ts
  @ ./src/Layer/Gerty/Component/Repository/AddGitHubRepository.tsx
  @ ./src/Layer/Gerty/Component/Repository/AddRepository.tsx
  @ ./src/Layer/Gerty/Component/Workspace.tsx
  @ ./src/Layer/Gerty/Component/App.tsx
  @ ./src/Layer/Gerty/GertyServiceProvider.ts
  @ ./src/Bundle/GertyElectron.ts
```

The only thing I can see that's suspicious at this point is that when I rebuild the module to work with electron, I only get a `Release` directory, when the import seems to be looking for `Debug`:

[image]

This could be a red herring however [as nodegit is written to try `Debug` as a fallback after `Release` has failed](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/generate/templates/templates/nodegit.js#L4-L16).

The general ask here is "How do I get this native module working in my project?".

I also have a [corresponding question over at the repo](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/1383), although on the off chance that my issue is unrelated to the library itself, or that there are some battle-worn veterans of native modules in electron, I figured SO would be a good place to check as well.

Comment: Hi, were you ever able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring your webpack by specifying the native module as an external dependancy rather than load it using the node-loader.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/